# Mongoose $push add to document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add an element to an existing array, but it produces an error:

```
The field 'data' must be an array but is of type object in document
```

Scheme:

```
const testScheme = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  data: [{
    platform: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    item_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    updatedAt: Date
  }]
}, {
  versionKey: false,
  timestamps: true
});
```

Document in mongodb:

```
"data": [{
        "price": 50,
        "_id": "5a84268d6c78a60c10479437",
        "platform": "pl1",
        "item_name": "test"
    }],
    "_id": "5a841bccb44cb8cd5b974d71",
    "user": "Ivan",
    "updatedAt": "2018-02-14T12:07:41.793Z",
    "createdAt": "2018-02-14T11:21:48.104Z"
```

Query:

```
var item = {
    "platform": "pl700",
    "item_name": "someText",
    "price": 700,
    "updatedAt": new Date()
  };
  Data.findOneAndUpdate({
      'user': 'Ivan'
    }, {
      $push: {
        'data': item
      }
    }, {
      safe: true,
      upsert: true
    },
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send({
        'error': err
      });
      res.status(200).send({
        'data': data
      });
    }
  );
```

I trying query with $set parametr and it works, but $push, $addToSet didn't work for me. Also i tried to google this problem and can't solve it.

Comment: So it looks like you are pushing the values into document(object) type as oppose to an array. You can run `db.colname.find( { data: { $type: "object" } } )` to view them and you can clean up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce using `node.js 8.9.4`, `mongod 3.4.13`, `mongoose 5.0.5`. Which versions do you use?

Comment: I restart mongodb and it's work with push! But I see if I make $set item document create like data:[Object] , but then I create with $addToSet and $push document create like data:[Array].

Comment: So now i have problem with update document object in array. I make  findOneAndUpdate with $attToSet parametr , but  item everytime creating new in array 'data'
"data": [{
            "price": 700,
            "_id": "5a85d8d4535aea1054f101ae",
            "platform": "pl700",
            "item_name": "someText",
            "updatedAt": "2018-02-15T19:00:36.056Z"
        }, {
            "price": 700,
            "_id": "5a85d9203fa0e40e5ca78b76",
            "platform": "pl800",
            "item_name": "someText",
            "updatedAt": "2018-02-15T19:01:52.909Z"
        }]

Comment: @Veeram,@hisener Thanks you for previous help! Can you help me a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you are intending to do.

To push an item into array you use `$addToSet/$push`. For updating a array you use `$set`.

Using `$set` you can update the whole document or you can update the specific field.

Update whole doc

```
Data.findOneAndUpdate({
      'user': 'Ivan',
      'data._id':item._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        'data.$': item
      }
    }...
)
```

Update specific field

```
Data.findOneAndUpdate({
       'user': 'Ivan',
       'data._id':item._id
     }, {
       $set: {
       'data.$.price': item.price
       }
    }...
)
```

Comment: Thanks you! It's very helpful